# Fetch records which columns as rows using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a table with columns as rows.

Now I want to apply restriction on multiple rows with "and" condition.how can we do this using hibernate criteria?

Example: `Employee` table

```
Pk  ColumnName.   Value
------------------------
1.  Empid.        10
1   EmpName.      Sachin
1.  Empsalary.    10,000
2   Empid.        20
2   EmpName.      Dhoni
2.  Empsalary.    8000
```

Now I want to fetch pk's which have `EmpName` as sachin and `empsal` as 10,000

So it should return pk as 1.

Please check image attached

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the primary key list of data from DB using criteria query. Follow the below code snippet:

```
EntityManager enm = sessFact.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder en = sessFact.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Integer> qu = en.createQuery(Integer.class);
    Root<Employee> ro = qu.from(Employee.class);
    qu.select(ro.get("id"));
    qu.where(en.like(ro.get("empName"), "Sachin%"), en.equal(ro.get("empSalary"), 10000 ));
    List<Integer> list= enm.createQuery(qu).getResultList();
    for (Integer name : list) {
       System.out.println("PK: " + name);
    }
```

in the where clause you can remove the **"%"** and give the exact search e.g., `qu.where(en.like(ro.get("empName"), "Sachin"), en.equal(ro.get("empSalary"), 10000 ));`

The equivalent SQL log generated by hibernate is in below:

> Hibernate: select employee0_.id as col_0_0_ from employee employee0_ where (employee0_.emp_name like ?) and employee0_.emp_salary=10000

FYI, The referred DB Table structure is as in below:

> CREATE TABLE `employee` (
>   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `emp_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `emp_address` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `emp_mobile_nos` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
>   `emp_salary` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Please find the complete code related to Hibernate in GIT here - https://github.com/ctmithun/HibernateExample/blob/master/Hibernate5Annotation/src/net/roseindia/GetAllData.java

Comment: Can you please share the equivalent sql for the above code

Comment: With simple criteria cant we do this? Please share sql

Comment: I believe this is simple, it only has 4 lines of code.                                 
Generated SQL: select employee0_.id as col_0_0_ from employee employee0_ where (employee0_.emp_name like ?) and employee0_.emp_salary=10000;

Comment: EmpName is not property in employee class

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you question "EmpName is not property in employee class", can you eloborate it?